# Spark - How to import dependencies that have .so files in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, import, pyspark, dependencies

Spark - How to import dependencies that have .so files in Spark?
Added dependency files dependencies.zip to --py-files. But .so files are not recognized. For example:

> > > import usaddress
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "usaddress/**init**.py", line 16, in 
> > >           import pycrfsuite
> > >         File "usaddress/pycrfsuite/**init**.py", line 2, in 
> > >           from ._pycrfsuite import *
> > >       ImportError: No module named _pycrfsuite